# rails and javascript firing twice on clicking back and forward button

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

How can i stop rails and javascript executing twice this image src on clicking back and forward button?

Rails code -- application.html.erb

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 
'reload' %>**
```

js code -- aa.js

```
 $(document).on('turbolinks:before-cache', function(event) {
 console.log("aastik");
 var scp = document.createElement('script');
 scp.setAttribute('src',''); //image https:// src
 scp.async = true;
 document.head.appendChild(scp);    
 });
```

rails -- secure.html.erb

```
<span id="siteseal">
<script async type="text/javascript"
 src="/javascripts/aa.js">
</script>
</span>
```

Comment: turbolinks 5.0 , rails 5.0.2

Comment: I am wondering, is it possible that `turbolinks` trigger that js code twice? because you trigger this at the event `turbolinks:before-cache` and then turbolinks will run the code also with `turbolinks:load`

Comment: by this it didnt show any image in starting but by ckicking on link the image occurs and it increases and increases on clicking links and back button

Comment: what i use to execute it single times only